# Twitch.tv Slowly Uses 100% Memory and then Freezes Computer

Tags: kubuntu, memory-usage, websites

Every time I try to access twitch.tv through Vivaldi, the memory usage on my system will slowly increase to almost 100% while the twitch.tv homepage does not finish loading. If I do not close the tab or window before it reaches almost 100%, the computer will freeze and the only option I have is to hold down the power button until the computer is forced to shut down. Twitch.tv is the only website that this occurs on; YouTube works just fine for me. Is there a way I can fix this issue?

Here is my system information:
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-43-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7600K CPU @ 3.80GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To limit any variables that might be causing this issue, have you tried running this site with a browser other than Vivaldi?

Comment: Create a swap file (Read `man free mkswap swapon fstab`). If you make it 1.0 x RAM size (or more), you can hibernate. Swap space lets you decide what happens when your programs exceed memory.  Without swap, it's as you described; with swap, your system slows down a little.

Comment: @richbl It works in Firefox; I'll see if I can inform the Vivaldi developers about the issue.